# how can i add diff images for single imageview for diff activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview

I am working with android app.I need to access the contents from `sqlite` to a single `xml` page which including text and image. How can I add different images for different activities in a single `ImageView` and `TextView`? I am new to android development. So please help me and thanks.

Comment: do you want to show multiple images in a single imageview? is that so?

Comment: I am done it with diff xml files for each page.but how can i load these into a single one for diff activities ??

Comment: Ya i want multiple image in single image view for diff actions . eg: when press button 1,button 2 etc diff image loaded in the same imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can use following source of code to change image in single image view.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
});
```

There may be different buttons event, but `imageView` will be same. So just change `drawable`s inside click event.